# Is it possible to use existing currency-code field with custom amount field when we are extending RAP BO?

Tags: currency, custom-fields, business-objects, extensibility, rap

I have extended a RAP BO with custom amount field.
Is it possible to use existing currency-code field for this custom amount field?

I have extended a RAP BO with custom amount field.
I want to use existing currency code field for the same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.